# Use Vue3 v-html without extra wrapping tag with script setup

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

How can I use vue's `v-html` directive in a Vue 3 `<script setup>` environment without an extra wrapping tag?

I want to be able to do something like this:

```js
<script setup>
const html = ref(`<pre></pre>`)
</script>

<template v-html="html"></template>
```

Comment: "Note that for some reason, although it works, this causes a 2-3 second delay" - this is XY problem, there's no evidence that extra wrapping tag causes it. Consider addressing it. The outmost <template> and inner ones are totally different things, "template" word is what they have in common

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Use a render function to make a functional component. Insert it either directly or with `<component>`. You can even change it dynamically without `<component>` or you can change the render function to issue different HTML:

```
<script setup>
  import {h, ref} from 'vue';
  const dynamic = ref(() => h('pre', {}, 'i am dynamic'));
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <component :is="() => h('pre', {}, 'i am a static PRE without a wrapper')"/>
    <dynamic />
  </div>
  <button @click="dynamic = () => h('input', {value: 'i was PRE'})">Change to INPUT</button>
</template>
```